# Adding Events to custom Listfielditerator

Tags: 2010, rendering-template

I'm rendering a custom FormTemplate that includes a ListfieldIterator. How can I add an event like onclick to one of my controls rendered by the iterator?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in ListFieldIterator you can try the following code:

```
protected override void RenderChildren(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (BaseFieldControl fieldControl in SPContext.Current.FormContext.FieldControlCollection)
    {
        if(fieldControl.Field != null && fieldControl.Field.InternalName=="BooleanFieldName")
        {
           //attach server-side event
           ((CheckBox)fieldControl).CheckedChanged += check1_CheckChanged;
           //attach client-side event
           ((CheckBox)fieldControl).Attributes("change","jsfunc();");
        }
        if(fieldControl.Field != null && fieldControl.Field.InternalName=="DateTimeFieldName")
        {
           //attach server-side event
           ((DateTimeControl)fieldControl).DateChanged+= dateTime1_DateChanged;
           //attach client-side event
           ((DateTimeControl)fieldControl).OnValueChangeClientScript="jsfunc();";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I don't know how to explain it. But if I got you right, I can add .NET events here!? How do I add javascript events like 'onclick' here? COul u please post another piece of code?

Comment: For what type of control do you want to add js event?

Comment: BooleanField-> change  and  DateTimeField -> onblur/lostfocus

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I'll try it now.